# Generating trigger spikes around a reference

Tags: analog, pwm, trigger

I'm experimenting with a circuit to use a IR2151 (self-oscillating half-bridge driver) as an el-cheapo MOSFET driver. Basically take away the "self-oscillating" part and trigger the high and low side MOSFET drivers using a microcontroller.

Why? Because I'm cheap. I got these neat little chips at about a third of the cost of a "real" MCU-drivable driver like the IR2104. That makes no sense to me because they are identical, except the IR2151 (and modern brother IR2153) has *more* capability, including an onboard 555-style pulse generator.

The short version:

How can I generate a 6V +/- 5V pulse train like this (in red), from a 5V PWM signal (in blue)?

[image]

The long version...

Here is my test circuit:

[image: IR2153 test circuit]

Under normal conditions, the IR2151/3 generates its own 50% duty cycle pulse train on pin 3 (Ct) using the resistor and capacitor between pins 2 (Rt) and ground.

The red trace (Vct):

[image]

As the voltage rises above about 5.5V, it triggers the LO MOSFET.
When it reaches about 10.5V, it switches off LO and introduces a short delay.
When it falls below 10.5V, HO switches on. LO stays off.
When it falls below 5.5V, HO switches off.
When it rises above 5.5V, the cycle repeats.

To control it with an external IO pin, I figured out it will work with the following pulse train. I say "figured out" because I am an amateur when it comes to this stuff and still learning.

[image]

Basically, a signal at 6V that spikes to 11V and later dips to 0V and repeats.

But how to generate such a signal from a PWM source?

Through LOTS more fumbling around, I got to this circuit:

[image]

It (red trace) produces this output from a square wave input:

[image]

But it doesn't work.

The peak is too low at 8V instead of 11V.
The trough is okay (dips below 5.5V), but going all the way to 0 would be better I think.

So my question is, is there a simple and elegant solution to get a 5V PWM signal to produce pulses that swing from ref VCC/2 to VCC on the high and VCC/2 to 0V on the low? Preferably without adding a bunch of transistors.

I kind of got it to work by using 3 diodes in parallel and shifting the mid-point. But this feels janky and the spike is too wide now.

[image]

This raises a second question... Why does my diode-based circuit (almost) work in the first place? I noticed using a Schottky diode provides a big swing, but using a normal diode a tiny one. Using diodes in parallel increases the peak, but also widens the pulse.

I have The Art of Electronics on my bookshelf, and will be glad to read up on this. If someone can please point me towards a chapter that covers the phenomenon I'm seeing.

Comment: OP amps with given voltage reference levels would be one way to do it. But then with the cost aspect I'm not sure if you are looking for the best technical solution or just a cheap compromise.

Comment: Did you try simple RC derivative circuit (series RC) connected between pwm and refference? The voltage across R should look like what you want. Choose RC tau like 1/20 of pwm pulse width.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I learnt that it is the capacitance of the diode in my model that create the "spike" - and I had some success replacing the diode for a capacitor. I get a good signal now, but the amplitude is still too low. I don't see any other way but to use an op-amp. Thank you for steer.

Comment: @Lundin I'm going the op amp route now. It's not really a cost issue but more a component count issue. Using a LM358 gives me the added advantage of providing a over-current protection circuit that will inhibit the driver, so it's a good compromise. But it is not plain sailing... I'm struggling a bit to get the spike to have "sharp" falling edges. I will persevere and report back here.